# iOS app auto resizing image uploads

Tags: support, status-completed, ios-app, images

I've uploaded a few images to posts using the iOS app recently and it seems the images are being auto resized—which is perfectly reasonable, but the images are being limited to 400 pixels in height. So my iPhone 6 screenshot, for example, turns out to be 225 x 400 pixels (and 50KB), which is pretty small.

Is there a way to upload images without this resizing? Or change the size limit?

Some examples: [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtIUw.jpg)], [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BJpA.jpg)], [[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXnTq.jpg)]

---

- App Version: 1.5.3.5
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.0.1 (Build 14A403)

Comment: Well, the android app does not resize, which results in most images being impossible to upload, as they are more than 2MB in size. So consider yourself lucky... That said, pretty sure the app is using [such code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137488/how-do-i-resize-the-uiimage-to-reduce-upload-image-size) with fixed size, so doubt you can change it. Hope Brian will prove me wrong though. :)

Comment: Hmm, yeh no resizing at all is probably worse. It would be easy enough to stick a conditional from a preference or ActionSheet choice in that code so maybe this'll need to be a feature-request. We'll see :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.0.7.

It is currently taking whatever image is uploaded, scaling it to a max size of 1024x400, saving it as a 100% quality JPEG, and uploading it.

This is the new logic:

1. If the image has a reference URL, fetch the data and mime-type from the photo library.
2. If the image is less than 1MB, upload as is.
3. Otherwise, take the image from the picker and convert it to a JPEG at 95% quality.  If that data is less than 1MB, upload it.
4. Otherwise, scale the image to (1MB / step 3 file size), then upload.

This means big images like the below history of the universe, can get away with a slight quality reduction, while things like a sweet unicorn gif can actually be uploaded.

[image: History of the universe]

[image: Unicorn gif]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Brian

Comment: Hold on... so there'll be no actual size reduction (as in pixels) at all anymore?

Comment: For anything under 1MB or that can be converted to a JPG under 1MB, no.  So most images should come through just fine.  Photos may be scaled some.

Comment: Of course, images are still scaled to `max-width: 100%` in the post view.

Comment: Sounds good! Slightly related... any idea where my beta app is? I signed up a while ago and thought new testers were signed up with new releases? :-)

Comment: Sent it out just now.  I'd forgotten to do it.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot Brian.