# Uploading gif from the app converts it into static jpeg

Tags: bug, android-app, ios-app, images

Trying to upload animated gif image from the app (both iOS and Android are affected) converts it into static jpeg image. No notice was made.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 11.1.2 (Build 15B202)

---

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 7.0 (172342203b663)

Comment: Wait, can you even store animated gif as-is over a mobile device? As far as I remember when trying to do that, it stored static image. So it might be the device "fault", not the app. To be sure, if you upload this same image to actual image host e.g. imgur, does it show the animated image fully?

Comment: @ShadowWizard this is not a device issue, I can see animated gif on device via built-in viewer at least.

Comment: Yeah, you're correct. Looks like the apps are not using imgur API correctly.

Comment: Hmm... something broke at some layer. I was [able to post a <1MB gif a year ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284740/ios-app-auto-resizing-image-uploads/284802#284802) but it turned into a jpg when I tried now. Could be a change in the iOS photo picker or the Imgur api. I say it could be iOS because the app doesn’t have access to what was previewed, just the asset that gets handed off after.

Comment: Fun fact, though: iOS 11 took the photo picker out of process with hosted views, so the permission prompt now only shows up after the image was selected and not before.

Comment: @BrianNickel did you return to iOS-app developing? Or just nostalgia?

Comment: Nostalgia.  I saw this bug and remembered that I got gifs working at one point.  No idea if they ever did on the Android app.